# How to ensure that connections will be reused in pool

Tags: java, sql-server, websphere, connection-pooling

I am having a problem that the DataSource is not reusing the connections it is creating a new one. The problem is then that it runs out of allowed connections.

I am using Java, MSSQL and Websphere.

Here is how I open the connection:

```
public static Connection open(boolean transaction) throws NamingException, SQLException {
    Context ctx;
    Connection con = null;
    ctx = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MYDB");
    if (ds == null) {
        throw new NamingException("No data source");
    }
    con = ds.getConnection();
    if (con == null) {
        throw new SQLException("No database connection");
    }else{
        con.setAutoCommit(!transaction);
    }
    return con;
}
```

In the finally of every DAO function I have a close function that closes everything.

```
public static void close(ResultSet rs, PreparedStatement ps, Connection con) throws SQLException{
    if (rs != null) {
        try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { throw e;}
    }
    if (ps != null) {
        try {ps.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { throw e;}
    }
    if (con != null) {
        if(con.getAutoCommit()){
            try { con.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { throw e;}
        }
    }
}
```

These functions I am working with are not transaction based connections. Every time the loop comes around to a function the code calls the open connection but instead of using one already established it creates a new one. I am monitoring the connections created in the Activity Monitor of the SQL Server Management Studio.

Any ideas why it is not reusing the connections?

EDIT: Here is the connection pool properties from Websphere:

[image: Websphere Connection pool properties]

**Solution:** 
So as it happens in most occasions, I was shooting my self in the foot. Turns out the close function above is correct but it is also being called in the Finally statement of a commit or rollback, which it wont close the connection. I changed the program to set the autocommit to true after a commit or rollback so it can close it correctly. And sure enough that was the issue.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Provide the configuration parameters for your datasource.

Comment: Also, why do you have a condition before closing the connection? This seems odd.

Comment: What class are you using for the datasource configuration? From MySQL or from Websphere?

Comment: I think you only need to create a datasource once.

Comment: @BenMinton OP's not creating a datasource, is being retrieved from JNDI.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the properties. I have these function centralized in a DAOManager class where it also controls if you are in a transaction, if so don't close the connection or create a connection depending on the function.

Comment: Your close method is leaking connections in two ways: 1) if exception happens during closing pstmt or rs, then you never call con.close() 2) if con.getAutoCommit() returns false you also don't close connection. You should always call con.close() as it returns connection to the pool. You also should not play with autocommit and if you have to make sure your resource reference is using 'unsharable' connections.

Comment: @Gas Thanks, I agree with 1 I powerful missed that. The only reason I check the autoCommit is because I place this close functions in every call even if it is being used in a transaction, thus the getAutoCommit() will be false. Those that use it with in a transaction have no problem. In fact it is only a few non-transaction calls that are having an issue. I did find in my code that not all calls are closing the result set and the prepared stmt, I am making sure they all use the above function for closing.